# How to create a Google Sheet formula for cumulative Interest rate?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Basaically I've 3 column. Column A, Column B, Column C

In Column A - Date is mentioned (04-Jan-2021)
In Column B - Amount is mentioned (2500)
In Column C - ???

Requirement:
So In column C, I want output with calculation of cumulative interest rate (7%) from the date mentioned in Column A till the today's date

So,internal calculation would be like this:
(2500 + 7%) = 2675 (2021-2022, 1 yr) | 2675 + 7% = 2682 (2022-2023, 1yr) | 2682 + 7% = 3062 (2023-2024, 1yr)

So, **in Column C expected value should be 3062.**

***Because 3062 is a total of investment + interest rate from last 3 yr with 7%.***

I tried out some ways, but I think this is more tricky

PS: Please use this table for calculation based on how much rate for how many days.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Suggestion:

Assuming that the date is in `A1` and the principal amount is in `B1`, you can calculate the new amount after cumulative interest rate is applied using the following formula:

```
=B1*(1+0.075)^ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(A1,TODAY()))*(1+
Let(dateDiff,DAYS(TODAY(),EDATE(A1,12*ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(A1,today())))), 
IFS(dateDiff<7, 0, (dateDiff >= 7) * (dateDiff < 31), 3.5%,
(dateDiff >= 31) * (dateDiff < 45), 3.8%, (dateDiff >= 45) * (dateDiff < 61), 4.25%, 
(dateDiff >= 61) * (dateDiff < 91), 4.6%, (dateDiff >= 91) * (dateDiff < 121), 4.75%,
(dateDiff >= 121) * (dateDiff < 181), 5%, (dateDiff >= 181)* (dateDiff < 211), 5.85%,
(dateDiff >= 211) * (dateDiff < 269), 6.1%, (dateDiff>=269) * (dateDiff < 363),6.35%,
dateDiff>=363,7.5%)))
```

Using your provided data, date of `04-Jan-2021` and principal amount of `2500`, as an example, the formula's output would be `3105.74`. Refer to the following for the breakdown of the computation:

```
2500 x 7.5% interest rate (for yr 2021-2022) = 2687.5
2687.5 x 7.5% interest rate (for yr 2022-2023) = 2889.06
2889.06 x 7.5% interest rate (for yr 2023-2024) = 3105.74
```

Note that the spreadsheet's locale may affect how formulas are formatted. I also can't find an alternative that shortens the formula aside from creating [named function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534) or a custom function via Apps script.

### References:

- [TODAY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984)
- [YEARFRAC()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092989)
- [EDATE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092974)
- [DAYS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061296)
- [IFS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145)
- [LET()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535)

Comment: Hi @Jimmy Trivedi. Was the answer above able to address your issue?

Comment: I'm still trying some test cases, you may also reverify here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/112d_tPU_Ycvy7d2Jz0pxAaE__cQC2uQUqw34MHdya-o/edit?usp=sharing